# fused relative word (whatever, whoever) + the hell/on earth

Tags: relative-clauses, modifiers, relative-pronouns

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*  has presented five reasons for classifying **ungoverned open exhaustive conditionals** not as fused relatives but as open interrogatives, and the fourth reason is on page 989 and shown here:

(An example of **ungoverned open exhaustive conditionals** is the underlined clause in [61] below, with or without *the hell*.)

[image: Extract from CGEL]

> (d) *Whatever the hell...*
> Ordinary interrogatives allow emotive modifiers like *the hell* or *on earth* to follow the interogative word: *What the hell do you want?* or *Who on earth said that?* This pattern is found also in the exhaustive conditional, as in the following attested example:
> [61]
>
> > *We [sc. women] must be attractive — w̲h̲a̲t̲e̲v̲e̲r̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲h̲e̲l̲l̲ ̲t̲h̲a̲t̲ ̲m̲e̲a̲n̲s̲ — because, without that we will find no place in this society.*
>
> Fused relatives do not admit these expressions: **̲W̲h̲o̲e̲v̲e̲r̲ ̲t̲h̲e̲ ̲h̲e̲l̲l̲ ̲s̲a̲i̲d̲ ̲t̲h̲a̲t̲ was wrong.*

But is it really true that fused relatives do not allow these emotive modifiers?

I have found quite a few examples from news articles and books, including these two:

> (1) But she just does [whatever **the hell** she wants to do at this point], and her record sounds like that. ([The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/music/2020/apr/16/rina-sawayama-lockdown-listening))
>
> (2) People believe what they want to believe, and it seemed that the Whitelaw Printworks lads wanted to believe that Hal Rashadam happened upon their team on a visit to [whoever **on earth** he might have known in the environs of Mile End Park]. ("Playing for the Ashes" By Elizabeth George)

Although the bracketed portions in (1) and (2) are fused relatives, 'emotive modifiers' such as *the hell* and *on earth* are used.

If these examples are legitimate, is it true that *Whoever the hell said that was wrong.* is ungrammatical for having *the hell*, and that in general, fused relatives do not allow these emotive modifiers?

Comment: From my quick reading of the definitions, I don't see that "Whoever said that" is necessarily a "fused relative".

Comment: @HotLicks What definitions from where? Please be specific.

Comment: The _like_ test would seem to say that both your examples are, in fact, subordinate interrogatives as they would become ungrammatical as a complement to _like : *_I don't like whatever the hell she wants to do at this point_ / * _I don't like whoever on earth he might have known in the environs of Mile End Park_

Comment: @DW256 AFAIK, the nature of the subordinate constructions is not predestined by the construction itself, but it's only determined by its syntactic environments. So, I'm afraid your _like_ test is neither here nor there, because my examples have different syntactic environments in which the subordinate constructions are embedded.

Comment: @JK2 The point is that _like_ does not license interrogatives, but does take fused relatives. Hence, it's a strike against judging these as fused relatives.

Comment: @DW256 You're not getting it. Both [i] _I liked what she wrote_ and [ii] _I wonder what she wrote_ have the subordinate construction _what she wrote_, but just because it passes the _like_ test in [i] doesn't mean it cannot be an interrogative clause in [ii]. In fact, it **is** an interrogative in [ii].

Comment: Take all such tests with a large pinch of salt. But don't consider a few counterexamples to constitute proof that a claim is invalid. Look in particular at the context of such counterexamples – register, and proficiency of speaker / writer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your comment is too general for me to fully understand. If you're talking about the _like_ test, it's not just "a few counterexamples". Please read my first comment to DW256 starting with 'AFAIK', if you can understand the general statement.

Comment: " '[T]o whoever on earth' ... is allowed". 'Having been used by X' and 'allowed' aren't exact synonyms. You could check for Svartvik & Greenbaum's investigations on the notion of 'acceptability' in English.

Comment: I do no not agree with CGEL that *Whoever the hell said that was wrong* is ungrammatical. It sounds perfectly natural to my American English ears. I don't know if any or all of these examples are fused relatives, but here are COCA's results for *whoever the hell*: https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=86977534

Comment: @TinfoilHat It sounded natural to my ear too, so I started this question. There is a paper that cites CGEL and this sentence. They too think it's ungrammatical (sentence 8 on page 1): http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1030.4547&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @TinfoilHat Also, the other commenters (HotLicks, DW256 and EdwinAshworth) seem to agree with CGEL that _Whoever the hell said that was wrong_ is ungrammatical.

Comment: Mm, no. They questioned whether *whoever* is a "fused relative" at all, insofar as it matters to CGEL.

Comment: And your reference quotes CGEL, so that is circular. I am not an expert in CGEL's interpretations of fused relatives vs. interrogatives (see COCA and let me know what those are), but I can assure you that *whoever the f*\*k downvotes my answer will have hell to pay* is grammatical

Comment: @TinfoilHat If the authors of the U of Essex paper had thought that CGEL's sentence is not ungrammatical, they would have objected to CGEL when they quoted the sentence. Moreover, they're not actually quoting CGEL; they themselves said the sentence is ungrammatical. As for the commenters here, I doubt that they think CGEL's sentence as grammatical or that they question CGEL's sentence in any way, shape or form. EdwinAshworth, for example, even attacked the validity of my own examples instead of CGEL's.

Comment: @TinfoilHat There are many examples in your COCA search that are 'fused relative' in CGEL. That's not surprising, because I have found quite a few 'fused relative' examples having the emotive modifiers in Google News/Books, only two of which are shown in the OP. // And the distinction is simple. If the 'wh-ever' subordinate construction is adjunct of the matrix clause, it's the exhaustive conditional, which CGEL classifies as an interrogative; if it's complement of the matrix clause, it's a fused relative.

Comment: If those COCA examples are "fused relatives", then fused relatives *can* be followed by *the hell* . . . or we just don't talk right. Let me know.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Also, I don't quite understand why you're not sure if _Whoever said that was wrong_ contains a fused relative. The issue is not whether that sentence contains a fused relative. In any grammar, CGEL or traditional, it does contain a (fused/free) relative. The issue is whether what CGEL calls an exhaustive conditional is a fused relative or an interrogative construction. And CGEL's objection to _Whoever the hell said that was wrong_ is simply being used as a reason to classify the exhaustive conditional, which allows _the hell_, not as a fused relative but as an interrogative.

Comment: You were questioning whether fused relatives allow emotive modifiers. CGEL says they don't and cites *Whoever the hell said that is wrong* as ungrammatical. You don't have to believe me, but it is grammatical. And whoever the hell stepped on my blue suede shoes is toast.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I hope we're right. It's actually funny, though, that you're talking about me not having to believe you, when I myself thought _Whoever the hell said that was wrong_ sounded natural, which got me started in the first place.

Comment: I agree that _Whoever the hell said that was wrong_ sounds ok, but _Whoever on earth said that was wrong_ much less so. Nevertheless, the CGEL's blanket statement that _Fused relatives do not admit these expressions_ is of dubious validity, as it seems to me that some such fused relatives in some contexts may be considered acceptable while others may not.

Comment: @Shoe Thanks for your input.